# Why does dynamic linking need the presence of SO files with GCC on Linux platform?

Tags: gcc, linker

Consider the following simple code using pthread:

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *thread(void *ptr) {
  long type = (long) ptr;
  printf("value: %ld\n", type);
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  pthread_t thread1;
  long value = 1;
  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, *thread, (void*) value);
  pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Running `gcc -o thread thread.c` will produce the following error:

```
/tmp/ccNBTPFM.o: In function `main':
thread.c:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
thread.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know that I should use `gcc -o thread thread.c -lpthread` to do the job. My question is why the SO file needs to be specified by `-lpthread`. My guess is that the linker needs to know the file name of the needed SO file such as `libpthread.so` at the link time and add the mapping between symbols (`pthread_create` and `pthread_join`) and the file name of the `pthread` library into the resulted program `thread`. As a result, when running `thread`, the linker can locate the SO file for definitions of `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` with the mapping.

I am using 16.04.5 LTS 64 bit and GCC 8.1.0.

Is my guess correct?

Comment: Can't reproduce your linkage failure, on my system or [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44f1af77dcf06fc5)

Comment: @MikeKinghan `cc -o thread thread.c` works for `clang` on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

When a dynamic executable is loaded, the dynamic linker will load all referenced .so files and then resolve all external symbols against all referenced libraries. The static linker is simply verifying that all external symbols can be found in some referenced library; in order to know what libraries it should reference, you use -l.

If, for example, you happened to know that the pthread functions are already in your runtime libc (but not your compile-time libc), you could use a flag like -Wl,—-undefined to tell the static linker to ignore an undefined symbol. At runtime the symbol will be found in the runtime library.